# I have problem with my store function in Laravel 9

Tags: php, sql, laravel, laravel-blade

basically every time I submit the form, the page refresh, and no items are stored in the DB. Here's the code.

```
PodcastController
    public function store(Request $request) {  
        $request->validate([
            'title' => 'required',
            'description' => 'required',
            'image' => 'image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,webp|max:2048',
            'audio' => 'audio|mimes:audio/mpeg',
            'category' => 'required',
        ]);
        if ($request->image) {
            $imageName = uniqid() . '.' . $request->image->extension();
            $request->image->move(public_path('podcast/images'), $imageName);
        }

        if ($request->audio) {
            $audioName = uniqid() . '.' . $request->audio->extension();
            $request->audio->move(public_path('podcast/audios'), $audioName);
        }
        Podcast::create([
            'title' => $request->title,
            'description' => $request->description,
            'image' => $imageName,
            'audio' => $audioName,
            'category' => $request->category,
        ]);

        return redirect()->route('podcast.list')->with('Success', 'Podcast Created!');
    }
```

Route

```
Route::resource(
    'podcasts',
    App\Http\Controllers\PodcastController::class
    );
```

create.blade.php

```
@extends('layouts.app')
@section('content')
    <div class="container">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <form action="{{ route('podcasts.store') }}" method="POST" enctype=multipart/form-data>
                @csrf
                <input class="form-control" type="text" name="title" placeholder="title">
                <input class="form-control mt-4" type="textarea" name="description" placeholder="description">

                <select name="category" class="form-control mt-4">
                    <option value="select" disabled>Are you a Creator or a User?</option>
                    <option value="news">News</option>
                    <option value="music">Music</option>
                </select>

                <label for="image" class="mt-3">Image</label>
                <input type="file" class="form-control" id="image" name="image">

                <label for="audio" class="mt-3">Audio</label>
                <input type="file" class="form-control" id="video" name="audio">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary mt-3">Submit</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
@endsection
```

The page keep refreshing everytime I run submit. I don't know where is the problem.

Comment: show your Podcast model

Answer (score 1):

You catching a failure while validating. After catching these validate errors, you should develop your code what to do.
https://laravel.com/api/9.x/Illuminate/Validation/ValidationException.html

```
try {
    $request->validate([
        'title' => 'required',
        'description' => 'required',
        'image' => 'image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,webp|max:2048',
        'audio' => 'audio|mimes:audio/mpeg',
        'category' => 'required',
    ]);
} catch (\Illuminate\Validation\ValidationException $e) {
    // do something...
    dd($e->errors());
}
```